# LINQ-to-SQL update query

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, entity

I'm having a problem with Link to SQL and updating a record, I think the problem is to with the current transaction based on the fact that I am looping through a connected data context:

```
    Using db = New PostcodeLookupModelContainer()

        Dim Stores = From b In db.lkpStores Where b.storeId ' = iStoreID '  Order By b.storeId

        For Each store In Stores

            Debug.Print(store.StorePostcode)

            Dim newStore As New lkpStores()
            newStore.depotId = store.depotId
            newStore.StorePostcode = store.StorePostcode
            newStore.depotId = store.depotId
            newStore.DepotDistance = store.DepotDistance

            db.lkpStores.Attach(newStore)
            newStore.DepotDistance = 50

            db.SaveChanges()

        Next store

    End Using
```

The line when I get the error is db.SaveChanges() and the error is 'New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session.'

Comment: Do you get the error on the 2nd time through the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to convert your "`Dim Stores = From b In db.lkpStores Where b.storeId ' = iStoreID '  Order By b.storeId`" to List() then loop it

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you need to attach the new object as it already exists.

```
db.lkpStores.Attach(newStore)
```

Just update the store object from the ForEach loop and call submit

```
   Using db = New PostcodeLookupModelContainer()

        Dim Stores = From b In db.lkpStores Where b.storeId ' = iStoreID '  Order By b.storeId

        For Each store In Stores
            store.DepotDistance = 50
            db.SaveChanges()
        Next store

    End Using
```

You could also refactor the code

```
   Using db = New PostcodeLookupModelContainer()

        Dim store = (From b In db.lkpStores Where b.storeId).SingleOrDefault 'Assumming the storeID is unique

        if store isnot nothing then
            store.DepotDistance = 50
            db.SaveChanges()
        end if

    End Using
```

Comment: I thought that also and tried it, it gives me the same error: 'New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session.'

Comment: Yes - the comment below fixed it, I need to change it to a list with ToList()